# Is it possible to import components as separate files in React native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make my react native app modular and hence creating JSX files as components. This is my App.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Header from './components/Header';
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

  export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header/>
      </View>
     );
   }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
      },
   });
```

In the Root folder where App.js is, I have a folder called component and a JSX file called Header.jsx.
The Header file looks like this

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { Text } from 'react-native';

  class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return <Text>This is a header component</Text>;
     }
    }

 export default Header;
```

But I get this error `Failed building JavaScript bundle.
Unable to resolve ./components/Header" from ".//App.js`: could not resolve `/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/myapps/moviedbapp/components/Header' as a file nor as a folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"`

I am pretty sure the path to the file and folder is correct when im importing it. I dont know what I am doing wrong please help.

Comment: and what do i import? index.js? or the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try import like this:

```
import Header from './components/Header.jsx';
```

Comment: Ok lastly, change the name of header.jsx to header.js and import header without extension. It should work.

Comment: Finally worked. So we cannot work with jsx files in react native?

Comment: Here is a discuss about this situation. Please take a look https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14438

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use parenthesis in return statement in  Header.jsx

```
  class Header extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <Text>This is a header component</Text>
       )
     }
    }
```

Use this.